# Angular - Mock subscribe in component's method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable, karma-runner

I have a method in a component which calls a service method like this:

```
method() {
    // Code before ...

    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        const products = [];

        // Many calculations on data ...

        this.products = products;
    }); 
}
```

For my unit tests I need to mock the returned data when `productService.getProducts()` is called.

I did many researches, but I didn't find any solutions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look [Component with async service](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-async-service). We can make the spy return a synchronous Observable with the test data for `this.productService.getProducts()` method.

Here is a working example using `angular` v11+:

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({})
export class ExampleComponent {
  products: any[];
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}
  method() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.products = data;
    });
  }
}
```

`product.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  getProducts() {
    return of(['Your real implementation']);
  }
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

fdescribe('54124518', () => {
  let productServiceStub: jasmine.SpyObj<ProductService>;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      productServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('ProductService', [
        'getProducts',
      ]);

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ExampleComponent],
        providers: [{ provide: ProductService, useValue: productServiceStub }],
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    })
  );

  it('should pass', () => {
    productServiceStub.getProducts.and.returnValue(of(['fake implementation']));
    component.method();
    expect(component.products).toEqual(['fake implementation']);
    expect(productServiceStub.getProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

[image]